# Returning wrong instances from functions

Tags: c++, function, return, instance, biginteger

I'm having trouble figuring out why my BigInt instances along with the custom vector class (BigIntVector) change when returning out of += into + functions. Looking to my example in main.cpp we have 40 + (-30) which in my BigInt.cpp code means it will turn that into 40-30 (and then print negative symbol at end because 'isPositive' bool is false). Using the debugger, I know for certain that -= returns the correct value of 10 into +=. Therefore in += 'tempThis' contains the vector with 10 in it and is returned to + function. However when it returns to the + function, 'tempThis' in that scope becomes 40? Any reason why?

Thank you.

BigInt.cpp addition

```
// binary addition
BigInt BigInt::operator+(BigInt const& other) const {

    BigInt tempThis = BigInt(*this);
    tempThis += other; //tempThis becomes 40 which isn't 10 for 40-30!!!!!!!
    return tempThis;
}

// compound addition-assignment operator
BigInt BigInt::operator+=(BigInt const& other) {

    if (!other.isPositive) {
        BigInt tempThis = BigInt(*this);
        tempThis -= other; //tempThis is correctly assigned 10 for 40-30!!!!!!!!
        cout << "get element at 0 +=: " << tempThis.bigIntVector->getElementAt(0) << endl;
        return tempThis;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
BigInt num11 = -30;

cout << "num11 (-30): " << num11 << endl;

BigInt num12 = 40;

cout << "num12 (40): " << num12 << endl;

BigInt num13 = num12 + num11;

cout << "num13 (-10): " << num13 << endl;
```

prints:

num11 (-30): -30

num12 (40): 40

num13 (-10): 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compound addition-assignment operator `+=` should be:

1. modifying its own value; and
2. returning a reference to itself, not a copy of its value.

The signature should be:

```
BigInt& BigInt::operator+=(BigInt const& other)
```

Within it, you don't want to use a temporary value, or possibly if you have failure conditions that might occur and want to guarantee behaviour, use a temporary variable and then overwrite your 'this' object if it succeeds.

Have a look at this page: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html
for more information. Search within the page for "Compound Assignment Operators" if you don't want to read the whole thing.

Comment: This was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the overload for the assignment operator and you need to return references to BigInt i.e.

```
BigInt& BigInt::operator+(BigInt const& other) const
```

Comment: I'm dumb. Unfortunately that print 40 instead of 30, which still ins't 10. updating post. 

40-30 should be 10 you are correct, but a isPositive boolean prints a negative in front when it is false. either way i'm looking for a 10 of something not 40

Comment: we've all been there. i spent an hour yesterday trying to work out why something was hanging and then found the sleep(20000) i'd added the day before

Comment: Unfortunately that only breaks things further. Any normal addition (without going into that if statement for a negative 'other') works perfectly fine and returns the right values. I suspect the problem lies somewhere in that if statement, I think I'm returning the wrong thing. Outside of that if statement I just return '*this'

Comment: @jankyCoder Can you please post the declaration for BigInt?

Comment: I understand what you were trying to say, but needed the += to be BigInt& instead